# Cocoa WebView to Mail.app

Tags: cocoa, email, webview, export

I know Safari has this feature using CMD + I. But is there a way I could integrate such a feature into an Objective-C app using a WebView?

Comment: You can listen for the keystroke and do the communication to mail through apple script. Please check this code for keystroke - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105468/cocoa-accepting-and-responding-to-keystrokes

Comment: Take a look at SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136513/how-can-i-send-a-html-email-from-cocoa